# Missing Keyword when trying to Select into

Tags: sql, oracle, function, keyword, scalar

So I have a function to return an Average of a column such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION avgCol
RETURN DEC IS avgNum DEC;
BEGIN
  SELECT AVG(myCol)
  INTO avgNum
  FROM MyTable;
  RETURN avgNum;
END;
/
```

While trying to test the results, i have the following

```
SELECT avgCol
INTO RESULT
FROM DUAL;
```

but it gives me the error

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 175 Column: 6
```

Where line 175 is `INTO RESULT`. As far as I know, this is a scalar function and I'm trying to return a signal variable so it should work right? What keyword am I missing here?
Also I know I can just use AVG(), but I am learning how to create a scalar function. this is strictly for learning purposes.

Comment: What is `avgCol`?  It doesn't appear to be defined anywhere.

Comment: What is `aveNum` in the function definition? That is what you are asking the function to RETURN.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it is a scalar function to return the average of the numbers in a column

Comment: @mathguy, sorry that was a typo. I changed my code up to post it here. Its meant to be avgNum

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, according to the documentation, it is a subtype
http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/predefined.htm#LNPLS2163

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While testing your code (which should be ok), you need

```
SELECT avgCol AS result FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Thank you! I looked it up and everywhere I looked it says to use 'INTO'. Do you know why I should use As instead of Into?

Answer (score 0):

'INTO' assigns the result value to a PL/SQL variable; 'AS' creates an alias/name for a SQL SELECT (not PL/SQL) result column/field.